# Dealing with django + celery when it goes offline

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to figure out how to deal with celery in my django project when it goes offline for some reason.

i found in the documentation the [worker-offline](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#worker-offline) event, so i am guessing i can somehow catch this event when celery goes offline and email myself informing my celery worker is down.

My question is how do i implement this behaviour? Are there any examples or a Django app? Is this how i am supposed to deal with these situations?

Comment: Why your worker goes offline? I use Celery in my Django application and I don't have this behavior. I run the celery in a daemon of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating this Django Reusable App with a REST API to monitor my celery workers from an external service or machine:
https://github.com/psychok7/django-celery-inspect

Answer (score 2):

In my production setup, I use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to daemonize and control celery workers. You can a have script running on the system monitoring the state of the supervisor controlled states (fire an alert anytime the [state of the process](http://supervisord.org/api.html#supervisor.rpcinterface.SupervisorNamespaceRPCInterface.getState) enters `FATAL` state).

Assuming your workers are continuously spitting out text in a log file, you can setup a log freshness check. If you detect the log has not been updated for X seconds/minute, you fire an alert.

There's also [Celery Flower](http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a system designed for remote monitoring and managing Celery remotely. I have not used it in production, so I cannot tell whether it meets your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can process events using real-time processing, write a consumer and announce when event come in, a example can be found in [Monitoring and Management Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing), replace the task-failed event with worker-offline event and write your own handler to deal with the event your captured.